# External CSS ,JS and Jquery in vscode webview api

Tags: javascript, css, api, webview, visual-studio-code

I want to use external CSS, JS, and JQuery in my HTML page in **VSCode WebView API**.

I have added below code to create webView with external CSS file, But my HTML page gets loaded without CSS, JS and JQuery change. I am not able to get how we need to refer this in the HTML page.

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('catCoding', "Cat Coding", vscode.ViewColumn.One, {
    enableScripts: true
});

const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(__dirname, 'src/webapp/css', 'styles.css'));

const webSrc = onDiskPath.with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });
```

I have added below code for Content-Security-Policy also in HTML to remove the restriction.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src vscode-resource: https:; script-src vscode-resource:; style-src vscode-resource:;">
```

Could you please let me know how to render HTML with external CSS, JS, and JQuery using VSCode web view API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to allow the access to src with localResourceRoots?

From the [cat example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_controlling-access-to-local-resources) where the content is in a media folder...

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as path from 'path';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('catCoding.start', () => {
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('catCoding', "Cat Coding", vscode.ViewColumn.One, {
            // Only allow the webview to access resources in our extension's media directory
            localResourceRoots: [
                vscode.Uri.file(path.join(extensionPath, 'media'))
            ]
        });

        const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(extensionPath, 'media', 'cat.gif'));
        const catGifSrc = onDiskPath.with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });

        panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(catGifSrc);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Hi Team, Sorry it was different issue and fixed it. Could you please me with below issue.

Comment: I have created tree view which has three children.i have implemented this using Custom view containers.

Referred below page for this change.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_extension-authoring

And i am loading webview for each child.

Comment: When i click on first child getChildren method gets called as per API functionality then i loaded webvew. corresponding webview loaded when click on second child also.

Issue is, when again click on first child nothing is happenning(getChildren method is not called). But i need to load corresponding webview for first child.

Is there any other API method we need to use for this?